# How to Protect third party iframe being used elsewhere

Tags: html, django, security, iframe, business-logic

I am using a third party (Company X) service for a part of my app (Django based) which is behind a secure login. The content from X is delivered in an iframe that is simply embedded in one of my pages.

I have spent a lot of time building the custom content in X's app (it is a custom, interactive geology tool) and my subscription with X is pricey as well. I want to protect against the possibility of one of my users sharing the iframe link with other coworkers or even users in other companies and simply using my content from X without even having to log into my app.

Unfortunately, X has no way to limit the iframe content by IP or any other type of link security. I know, sounds crazy but that's the way it is right now.

What would be the best way to build my own security solution? Is there a way to use another server as an intermediary so that when the client opens the page my live server hits my intermediary server that fetches the content from X? 
Then, I am the only one to accept requests on my intermediary server from my live server.

Answer (score 2):

If Company X provides its service without authentication (anybody can just download it in a frame), that's a problem on their end that you will not really be able to fix in your code. Even if you hide the actual iframe url, it will still work for anyone that has the link. But you are right, at least not all of your visitors will have it, and that may be good enough, it is a risk that can be accepted if you want to.

Your idea of putting a server inbetween, and your application only accessing the interim one could actually work. This is called a reverse proxy, any web server software (Apache, nginx, IIS, etc.) can do it without much setup. So no development is needed, and hence setting it up is not a programming question.

What *is* a programming question is the security of this solution. You need to be aware that while this would hide the iframe url from your users, that url would still be valid and would work for anyone, this is an issue with Company X's service. Also you need to have *authentication on the reverse proxy server*, otherwise the new iframe url can be copied just as well as the original one.

Also be aware that reverse proxying a complex website with lots of embedded resources and javascript will have its pitfalls. Depending on actual contents, the real origin may sometimes be disclosed to your users.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the response header **'X-Frame-Options'** to **'sameorigin'**..

Please refer this...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

It's used to disable the Iframe (except your server)..

Comment: But this should be set on Company X's service, which @acandroid clearly cannot do.